# Building graph from database structure to implement A* algorithm?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting, osm2pgsql, graph

I imported an osm file into a postgresql database using osm2pgsql.

Now, I want to implement a route/path generating algorithm (routing algo) based on two locations entered by a user.

It is not really clear for me where in my database structure I should search for these two points. For example if a user enters as starting point "Airport A" and as end point "Airport B" where should I search for these two locations so I can start implementing my routing algorithm.

I need some clear information on how the database is structured and how to create a graph so that i can implement A* algorithm between the 2 points the user has enetered.

Comment: Your question is a bit vague. As all of what you ask has already been done, as very well outlined by @Thingamabob, so you should probably digest that first, which will answer how to do it yourself.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest to have a look at

- the osm2pgsql specific

  - [line schema description](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql/schema#planet_osm_line_schema_documentation)
  - [database layout](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/pgsql.md#database-layout)
  - [OSM wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osm2pgsql#Osm2pgsql_schema)
  - [general docs](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql) and [command line docs](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/usage.md)
  - [style file](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/default.style)
  - [spatial analysis example](https://github.com/openstreetmap/osm2pgsql/blob/master/docs/analysis.md)
- the [OSM tags](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags), very intensively, to be able to identify what you are looking for
- your database structure after import

To start with, the database will (at least, read about *slim mode* at one of the above links) contain four tables:

1. *planet_osm_point*
2. *planet_osm_line*
3. *planet_osm_roads*
4. *planet_osm_polygon*

but you have almost full control over how the tables are structured (specifically what tags will be imported as columns or if and how they will be added as hstore key/value pairs) via the style file!

Now, getting this done properly might help you reverse geocoding the user input to a set of features. OSM data however has a *very* complex and *very* exhaustive feature/relation/tag system and you will most likely end up with a dozen different features for 'Airport A' if not meticulously specified or limited further.

A much greater pain in the will  be to create the routing graph. OSM road line features by themselves are far from topologically correct and will have hundreds of thousands of dangling ends and unconnected segments and whatnot, and countless road types and restrictions coded in the tags...honestly, if I were asked to do that for an area larger than my backyard, I would go get myself fired.
Why the gloomy tone? There were great minds at work for you to have it easier!
I strongly recommend you do have a look at pgRouting, as @akadouri suggested - especially at [osm2pgrouting](https://github.com/pgRouting/osm2pgrouting) (note the patch at the bottom of the page), which will create that graph for you based on a pgRouting-friendly (but very rational) schema strucure.
There's also [OSM Nominatim](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim), which does all the tedious reverse geocoding search implementation for you. From there, it´s 'merely' a question of identifying the closest node as an entry/exit point for your routing algorithm...
You can still go and implement your A* yourself alright, but use the *very* useful routing and searching data structure that is provided by those tailored tools.

Comment: A much greater pain, lol. No kidding.

Comment: (off topic: to any english native reading this: in the context above, is it '...if I *was* asked...' or '...if I *were* asked...'? don't mind any other mistakes I made for today's lesson ,) )

Comment: If I were asked, but if I was asked has become common in everyday usage. Interestingly, this is one of the few surviving examples of the subjunctive in English.  I live in Spain, where the subjunctive is alive and well and did Latin at school, so I know a subjunctive when I see one. I never expected it to come up in the context of pgrouting :D

Comment: @JohnPowellakaBarça hehe...I guess the wrong routing can lead you anywhere!? Thx for the lesson Professor Powell, I'll correct it ASAP!

Comment: Ha, ha, yes, well, your English is considerably better than my German, which I did for two years in school.

Answer (score 0):

Look into [pgRouting](http://pgrouting.org/index.html), an extension to PostGIS that enables routing support.

Comment: I didn't want to know a built service that helps me do so.I need to make the routing algorithm.I just want to know:   1)how the database is structured 2)how and which nodes should I get from the data to make a routing algorithm using A*

Comment: Well, if you had a look at the existing implementation, those questions would be answered for you.